# ionic3 ios -14 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cordova, ionic3

Please help me on the below issue on ios with ionic3.

after adding WKWebView, getting the below issue

duplicate symbol '*OBJC_IVAR*$_CDVWKWebViewEngine._engineWebView' in:
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fecbd1bab0d29c98dab5aac6c5507fc26.o
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200f4eac2c233cf469761f8b647b7bed3a48.o
duplicate symbol '*OBJC_IVAR*$_CDVWKWeakScriptMessageHandler._scriptMessageHandler' in:
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fecbd1bab0d29c98dab5aac6c5507fc26.o
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200f4eac2c233cf469761f8b647b7bed3a48.o
duplicate symbol '*OBJC_IVAR*$_CDVWKWebViewEngine._weakScriptMessageHandler' in:
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fecbd1bab0d29c98dab5aac6c5507fc26.o
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200f4eac2c233cf469761f8b647b7bed3a48.o
duplicate symbol '*OBJC_CLASS*$_CDVWKWeakScriptMessageHandler' in:
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fecbd1bab0d29c98dab5aac6c5507fc26.o
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200f4eac2c233cf469761f8b647b7bed3a48.o
duplicate symbol '*OBJC_METACLASS*$_CDVWKWeakScriptMessageHandler' in:
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fecbd1bab0d29c98dab5aac6c5507fc26.o
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200f4eac2c233cf469761f8b647b7bed3a48.o
duplicate symbol '*OBJC_IVAR*$_CDVWKWebViewEngine._uiDelegate' in:
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fecbd1bab0d29c98dab5aac6c5507fc26.o
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200f4eac2c233cf469761f8b647b7bed3a48.o
duplicate symbol '*OBJC_CLASS*$_CDVWKWebViewEngine' in:
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fecbd1bab0d29c98dab5aac6c5507fc26.o
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200f4eac2c233cf469761f8b647b7bed3a48.o
duplicate symbol '*OBJC_METACLASS*$_CDVWKWebViewEngine' in:
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fecbd1bab0d29c98dab5aac6c5507fc26.o
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewEngine-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200f4eac2c233cf469761f8b647b7bed3a48.o
duplicate symbol '*OBJC_CLASS*$_CDVWKWebViewUIDelegate' in:
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewUIDelegate-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fa5bb3efc64238d58cc9e9e64bd3fb72d.o
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewUIDelegate-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fbcf3510f7884c3b6cb9d7de2b7608c59.o
duplicate symbol '*OBJC_METACLASS*$_CDVWKWebViewUIDelegate' in:
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewUIDelegate-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fa5bb3efc64238d58cc9e9e64bd3fb72d.o
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewUIDelegate-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fbcf3510f7884c3b6cb9d7de2b7608c59.o
duplicate symbol '*OBJC_IVAR*$_CDVWKWebViewUIDelegate._title' in:
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewUIDelegate-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fa5bb3efc64238d58cc9e9e64bd3fb72d.o
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKWebViewUIDelegate-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fbcf3510f7884c3b6cb9d7de2b7608c59.o
duplicate symbol '*OBJC_CLASS*$_CDVWKProcessPoolFactory' in:
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKProcessPoolFactory-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200f090067d193c064783645cabf0158f16b.o
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKProcessPoolFactory-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fa623ccce1abe67f1eb502a1dfd737920.o
duplicate symbol '*OBJC_METACLASS*$_CDVWKProcessPoolFactory' in:
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKProcessPoolFactory-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200f090067d193c064783645cabf0158f16b.o
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKProcessPoolFactory-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fa623ccce1abe67f1eb502a1dfd737920.o
duplicate symbol '*OBJC_IVAR*$_CDVWKProcessPoolFactory._sharedPool' in:
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKProcessPoolFactory-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200f090067d193c064783645cabf0158f16b.o
/Users/srinivas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Socionet-dpbbadihbrnhywhjhuahttldnzau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Socionet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Socionet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVWKProcessPoolFactory-6dce158b347d27ebf4f8f1b8a515200fa623ccce1abe67f1eb502a1dfd737920.o
ld: 14 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)